# How do I Bind ContextMenu.Visibility of a ListViewItem to property of viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have two property in  viewModel for visiblity ContextMenu and ContextMenuItem.

```
   /// <summary>
    /// show context
    /// </summary>
    bool _showContext;
    public bool ShowContext
    {
        get { return _showContext; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _showContext)
            {
                _showContext = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ShowContext");
            }
        }
    }

       /// <summary>
    /// can archive
    /// </summary>
    bool _isArchiveContext;
    public bool IsArchiveContext
    {
        get { return _isArchiveContext; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isArchiveContext)
            {
                _isArchiveContext = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsArchiveContext");
            }
        }
    }
```

and in Xaml, i use two method for binding. But don't binding.

```
 <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.ShowContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu},Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}">
<MenuItem Header=" بایگانی"
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ArchiveCommand}"  Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=IsArchiveContext,Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=SelectedItems}" />




<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

First Thing that I would like to tell you is that if its an MVVM framework , you could bind Visibility like This

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" Visibility="{Binding ShowContext},Converter={StaticResource ToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

I hope that you have the `ToVisibilityConverter` already in a class file

Comment: Thanks, but `ContextMenu` is for ListViewItem, so don't i use `Binding ShowContext` . I use `RelativeSource `.